# I am using try-and-except in a function. And other functions which can cause value errors, but it doesn't raise Exception. IDW?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Here's the code:

```
def TryExcept(foo):
    try:
        print('Using TryExcept')
        foo()
    except (ValueError, TypeError):
        print('Type or Value Error')

def add(a,b):
    print(f'Variables : {a} and {b}')
    print(int(a)+int(b))

TryExcept(add(1,2))
TryExcept(add('a','b'))
```

Comment: In `TryExcept(add('a','b'))`, the function call `add('a','b')` is evaluated before `TryExcept` is called. It would raise an exception but it would not be inside your `try` block when it does.

Comment: And as you are not returning anything from foo, you basically do that: `TryExcept(None); 
TryExcept(None)`

Comment: @khelwood So how do I make it work?

Comment: You could pass a lambda function into `TryExcept` if you really want to do this. E.g. `TryExcept(lambda: add('a','b'))`.

Comment: It prints `Type or Value Error` twice, by the way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial) as an argument to your try/except function:

```py
from functools import partial

TryExcept(partial(add, 1, 2))
TryExcept(partial(add, 'a', 'b'))
```